# My question about coding seems to have a pure hardware answer. Now what to do with this?

Tags: support, questions

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19554479/343721) which seems to have a pure hardware answer. Does it still belong on SO?

I wrote down compatible pieces of hardware from the comments to the end of the question. Is it a good idea? What should I do with the question now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question looks valid, since it's about a programming issue.

However you should answer your own question, instead of including the answer in the question body.